# Pass array into a single column in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

i am trying to pass some values into a single column in laravel database table.

The values are like this 20,45,67,89

but i want them to enter into the colume like this

===USER_ID====
20 
45
67
89

I have tried like below, but not working..any suggestions ?

```php
foreach ($request->val2 as $value){

    $str_explode = explode(",",$value);

    DB::table('retirement')->insertGetId([
        'user_id' => $str_explode,
        'amount'  => $request->val1,
        'week' => $request->week

    ]);
}
```

Comment: You mean, you want to add same amount and same week values for all user_id?

Comment: yes...but this values are from a dynamic table in a blade

Answer (score 0):

`explode()` is returning an array, not a single value, that's why it will fail. Instead, you should loop through all values like this:

```php
foreach ($request->val2 as $value){

    $str_explode = explode(",",$value);

    foreach($str_explode as $str){
        DB::table('retirement')->insertGetId([
            'user_id' => $str,
            'amount'  => $request->val1,
            'week' => $request->week
        ]);
    }
}
```

As a side advice, as you are not saving the id returned by `insertGetID`, you can simply use `insert`. Moreover, it's usually a good practice to use `create` because this way you will also save timestamps for created and updated.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work

```
 foreach ($request->val2 as $value){

 $str_explode = explode(",",$value);

 $insert = [];

 foreach($str_explode as $str){

     $insert[] = [
                   'user_id' => $str,
                   'amount'  => $request->val1,
                   'week' => $request->week
                 ];
 }

 DB::table('retirement')->insert($insert);
```

Comment: there is a syntax error in this code pls help check

Comment: @carte Your first `foreach` loop doesn't have it's closing curly brace.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i understood your question clearly, i'm assuming you want to insert array to a column:

- did you try to set the column in migration to Json?
- did you set the $casts in the model to json or array?

```php
protected $casts = [ 'user_id' => 'array' ];
```

then when you do this, you can have an array added to that column like

```php
Posts::create(['user_id'=>[1,2,3,4]]);
```

normally the user_id field is set to `unsignedBigInt()`, that type will not accept anything but integers, you gotta check the migration column type first.